# How to hide <article> in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am working with HTML5. I am stuck with **hiding article**.
Actually, I used `<article class='LabResultRegistration_SchemaForm' hidden>` to hide. It is working fine. But, I used the same for another `<article>`, for it, is not working. When I check code in inspectelement I can see `style='display: block;'` with it. If I uncheck that style it is hiding. But, I cant see any style in my actual code.

This is my actual code:

```
<article class='SamplePoints_SchemaForm' hidden>
  <header >
    <hgroup>
      <h2  data-bind="html:setMLString('ImportCM^SamplePoints')">Import</h2>
    </hgroup> 
  </header><br/>
  <Label data-bind="html:setMLString('ExtIdCM^CM^ExtId')" >ExtId</Label>
  <input type='text' class='k-textbox TEAMSTextbox' data-bind='value:SamplePointsselected.ExtId.Value'  id='SamplePoints_Text_ExtId' onblur='SamplePoints_Text_ExtId_onblur(event)' onchange='SamplePoints_Text_ExtId_onchange(event)'   maxlength=250 />

</article>
```

And also, can I use data-bind='' for hidden. If I can, how can I bind it (with an example).

Comment: Which css wrote for class SamplePoints_SchemaForm?

Comment: Maybe some scripts adds display block on it

Comment: There is no CSS for this HTML. But, I can see CSS in inspectElement
Inline style {
display: block;(it has checked)
}

Comment: Can you give link on you project? This will help to define problem

Comment: You mean...?
Which link?

Comment: Can i have access to web page with problem from web?

Comment: Also try to use search by your code, first of all try to search js code with such string "SamplePoints_SchemaForm"

Comment: I am running this in my local computer. It doesn't has any global link. there is no "SamplePoints_SchemaForm" in js code.

Comment: ok try to remove class "SamplePoints_SchemaForm" from article block, will it has style with display: block after page reload.

Comment: I removed class='SamplePoints_SchemaForm'. Still it has style="display: block" in output.

Comment: Now try to search scripts with word 'article' )

Comment: Nothing is in JS with 'article'.

Comment: If you use jquery try to execute ​$._data( $("article.SamplePoints_SchemaForm")[0], "events" ); in console and show result

Comment: I am using javascript.

Comment: Try to use http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event, it will help you to find which events binded to article element